# JPA Criteria API Join unidirectional Many-to-one entity with multiple tables

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria, derby

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
public class IssueAssignment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Assignee assignee;

    @ManyToOne
    private Issue issue;

    public IssueAssignment() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getAssigneeId() {
        return getAssignee().getId();
    }

    public int getIssueId() {
        return getIssue().getRowId();
    }

    public Assignee getAssignee() {
        return assignee;
    }

    public void setAssignee(Assignee assignee) {
        this.assignee = assignee;
    }

    public Issue getIssue() {
        return issue;
    }

    public void setIssue(Issue issue) {
        this.issue = issue;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Assignee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String userName;

    public Assignee(String userName) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Assignee() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}

@Entity    
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id", 
"author", "created", "state", "url", "appId" }) })
public class Issue implements Labelable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int rowId;
    private String id;
    private String author;
    private Timestamp created;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Lob
    private String body;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Lob
    private String title;

    private String state;
    private String url;
    private int appId;
    private String milestone;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "issue", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "issueId")
    private List<IssueLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "issue", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "issueId")
    private List<Participant> participants = new ArrayList<>();

    public Issue() {

    }

    // getters and setters
```

What I am trying to do know is to write a function that returns all Issues that were assigned to a Assignee with a certain assigneeId. In essence, I want to create the following SQL query as a Criteria API query:

```
SELECT Issue.* from IssueAssignment join Issue on
IssueAssignment.issue_rowId = Issue.rowId where IssueAssignment.assignee_id =
<some number>
```

This is what I have so far (adapted from http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/04/28/criteria-api-joins/):

```
public List<Issue> getAllAssignedIssues(int assigneeId) {
    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName).
    createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Issue> query = cb.createQuery(Issue.class);
    Root<IssueAssignment> issueAssignment = query.from(IssueAssignment.class);
    Join<IssueAssignment, Issue> issues = issueAssignment.join(IssueAssignment_.issue);
    query.select(issues);
    List<Issue> resultList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

The first problem here is that the join doesn't seem to work because I get a cross join between the Issue table and the IssueAssignment table instead of a inner join on Issue.rowId = IssueAssignment.issue_rowId. The second problem is that I don't know how to write the where clause. The problem is that the table columns for assignee_id and issue_rowId in IssueAssignment are generated by JPA, so I can't just write

```
.where(cb.equal(IssueAssignment_.assignee_id, assigneeId));
```

Is there a way to directly work with the correct Assignee instance so I can do something like:

```
.where(cb.equal(IssueAssignment_.assignee.getId(), assigneeId));
```

If not, it seems that I also have to do a join on Assignee. I know that you can chain joins like:

```
ListJoin<Issue, Participant> participants = issues.join(Issue_.participants);
```

But is there a way to do a join that results in something like the following?

```
Join<Assignee, Issue> issues = ...
```

If that were the case, I believe I could then get the correct results with

```
select(issues).where(cb.equal(Assignee_.id, assigneeId));
```

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is trying your query in JPQL and seeing if you get the results/SQL you expect.  It is just generally easier to do and read (IMO), and is a simple conversion to criteria api from there.  Chances are though your issue will be with the IssueAssignment.assignment mapping.  If you want to use the foreign key and compare with a straight value, you might want to map it as a basic mapping for use in your queries, or add a query key (EclipseLink specific functionality) for it.  Otherwise, to do a straight Issue-Assignee mapping, why keep the IssueAssignment entity?

Comment: Another comment is that how are you verifying you are getting a cross join instead of the expected inner join?  Try posting the SQL that is generated https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging  Another comment is that your OneToMany mappings specify both the 'mappedby' clause as well as a joincolumn.  You should remove the joincolumn annotations from those mappings, as the join column is picked up from the mapping specified in the 'mappedby' specification.

Comment: @Chris This JPQL query works correctly:    TypedQuery<Issue> query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT i from IssueAssignment ia JOIN ia.issue i JOIN ia.assignee a where a.id = :assigneeId",
    Issue.class).setParameter("assigneeId", assigneeId); and produces the sql: SELECT t0.ROWID, t0.APPID, t0.AUTHOR, t0.BODY, t0.CREATED, t0.ID, t0.MILESTONE, t0.STATE, t0.TITLE, t0.URL FROM ISSUE t0, ASSIGNEE t2, ISSUEASSIGNMENT t1 WHERE ((t1.ASSIGNEE_ID = ?) AND ((t0.ROWID = t1.ISSUE_ROWID) AND (t2.ID = t1.ASSIGNEE_ID)))

Comment: @Chris I saw that it is a cross join because the size of the list was number of Issues times number of IssueAssignments. You are right, though, maybe I should just scrap the IssueAssignment entity and have a many-to-many mapping between Issue and Assignee with a join table.

Comment: @Chris Looking at that SQL query again, it is weird that it turns the where clause from assignee.id = assigneeId into issueassingment.assignee_id = assigneeId and then does a useless cross join with assignee anyways.

Comment: You are doing a join of the main entity and the relation table (IssueAssignment), which will give you an Issue row for every IssueAssignment row that matches the query, the same as SQL would.  You will want to get only the distinct Issues

Comment: As for the SQL - it is following the joins you specified in the query.  join ia.issue creates the "(t0.ROWID = t1.ISSUE_ROWID)" clause, while join ia.assignee forces the "(t2.ID = t1.ASSIGNEE_ID) clause.  EclipseLink might be able to optimize out that last join if you hadn't explicietely put it in your JPQL.  "select i from IssueAssignment ia JOIN ia.issue where ia.assignee.id = :assigneeId" might work for you to avoid the extra join, but I wouldn't rely on it.  If I were to be sure to avoid the join, I would instead add a basic mapping for the foreign key, and use that in the query instead.

Comment: @Chris "ia.assignee.id = :assigneeId" indeed works. But is there a way to do this with a criteria api query? As for the join with issue, i am joining on the primary key of issue so I won't get duplicate issues from there. I also made sure that there are no duplicate issueassignments in the table and I will add a unique constraint later.